# VBA Late Binding for MAC

Tags: vba, macos, outlook, late-binding

I need help to make this vba code to work in mac (it's running perfect under windows but I have users that have only mac), the code extracts body data from selected emails in outlook and sends the info to a sheet.

I tried reading all the posts here about late binding and I got how it works, basically not referencing libraries that doesn't exist in mac office versions. I've changed the line that is causing trouble in my code "Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem" for "Dim objMail As Object" it runs, but the macro goes directly to the msg box line without performing anything (I think ohh is running the code but I've tried debugging it but is not getting any variable or any information when I run it and I didn't get any error msg)

```
Sub DetailExtraction()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") ' late binding

' CREATE AND SET A NameSpace OBJECT.
Dim objNSpace As Object
' THE GetNameSpace() METHOD WILL REPRESENT A SPECIFIED NAMESPACE.
Set objNSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' CREATE A FOLDER OBJECT.
Dim myFolder As Object
Set myFolder = objNSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim Item As Object
Dim iRows, iCols As Integer
iRows = 2

' LOOP THROUGH EACH ITEMS IN THE FOLDER.
'For Each objItem In myFolder.Items
' LOOP THROUGH EACH ITEMS IN THE SELECTION.
For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
    
        Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set objMail = objItem

        Cells(iRows, 1) = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
        Cells(iRows, 2) = objMail.To
        Cells(iRows, 3) = objMail.Subject
        Cells(iRows, 4) = objMail.ReceivedTime
        Cells(iRows, 6) = objMail.Body
        Cells(iRows, 6).WrapText = False
        'MsgBox Prompt:=objMail.Body
   End If
    
   'WRAP UP FILE OFF
  ' Cells*i.WrapText = False
    ' SHOW OTHER PROPERTIES, IF YOU WISH.
    'Cells(iRows, 6) = objMail.Body
    'Cells(iRows, 5) = objMail.CC
    'Cells(iRows, 6) = objMail.BCC
    'Cells(iRows, 4) = objMail.Recipients(1)
    
    iRows = iRows + 1
Next
Set objMail = Nothing

' RELEASE.
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objNSpace = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
ErrHandler:
Debug.Print Err.Description
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Environments Details Extracted from the Selected Emails (" & iRows - 2 & ")"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what you are saying is that if you put a breakpoint on the `For Each` line, and then advance one step, it completely skips the loop? If so, there is something wrong with `ActiveExplorer.Selection` - or does it make it to the `If` statement?

Comment: @braX if I comment the Error Handler the error is in the line:
`Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`
vba runtime error 429 activex component can't create object - at least is running now...

Comment: if you cannot create the object, then it would seem you do not have Office/Outlook installed on that computer... do you have Outlook installed? it doesn't automatically come with the computer...

Comment: yeah I have a mac with an office corporate license, same license I'm using in a virtual box with windows and I can run this without problems, if I got no solution may be I will let them know they have to install virtual box to run this macro on windows. 
I can run other macros in mac as well that not reference any outlook libraries.

for me the CreateObject(""Outlook.Application") is referencing the Outlook Library when it tries to create the object.

Comment: I dont use macs, but other sources i looked up all point to this page... it may help - http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm#Mail

Comment: thanks for your support Brax I will take a look. :)

Comment: COM is not available on Macs, which means that you can't use Outlook automation as you're trying to do. COM is a Windows-only technology.

Comment: Unfortunately, Office doesn't have an object model for outlook on mac **yet** (it has for word & powerpoint). As a work around follow the link provided by @braX. As a side note, whenever you're changing to late binding, you should remove the reference to the library so that any problems may be highlighted. In your code you're using constants such as `olMail`. You either have to define these constants or use their actual values  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa219371(v%3Doffice.11)